# How do I specify the device using decodebin in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I like using decodebin because it selects the right container/parser and decoder type for any file or stream but I have several GPU's in my system and want to balance the workload across multiple GPUs.  I can use nvh264device1dec for example, to use the second GPU when I create a pipeline myself, but I want to use decodebin and specify a device to use.  Is this possible?